# Netty decoder memory consumption

Tags: netty, heap-memory

I use Netty IO (4.0.29 Final) to decode bytes that come from a TCP server. In first position of my pipeline, I use LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder to split bytes in frames (this handler works fine). In second position of my pipeline I implemented my own handler that extends ByteToMessageDecoder of Netty.

In this custom handler, I want to do several actions :

1. Converting bytes to an hexadecimal representation for recording in
   text file,
2. Verifying checksum of the frame,
3. Aggregating frame(s) based on bytes #14 and #15 which representing respectively segment number and segment total count (so when segment number is equals to segment total count, my buffer is complete and it can sent to the next handler).

   ```
   private ByteBuf aggregate;
   private short lastSegmentId;

   @Override
   protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in,
       List<Object> out) throws Exception
   {
       String hexDump = ByteBufUtil.hexDump(in);
       RecordingService.record(hexDump);

       in = in.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

       byte segId = in.getByte(14);
       byte segCnt = in.getByte(15);

       int readableBytes = in.readableBytes();

       int sum = 0;
       for (int index = 0; index < readableBytes-2; index++)
       {
           short s = in.readUnsignedByte();
           sum += s;
       }
       int checksum = in.readUnsignedShort();

       if (sum == checksum)
       {
           //
           // Checksum correct
           //  
           if (segId == (lastSegmentId + 1))
           {
               lastSegmentId = segId;
               byte[] byteArray = new byte[readableBytes-18];
               in.getBytes(16, byteArray, 0, readableBytes-18);
               aggregate.writeBytes(byteArray);

               if (lastSegmentId == segCnt)
               {
                   aggregate.readerIndex(0);
                   out.add(aggregate.copy());
                   lastSegmentId = 0;
                   aggregate.clear();
               }
               else
               {
                   lastSegmentId = 0;
                   aggregate.clear();
               }
           }
           else
           {
               //
               // Checksum not correct
               //
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This custom handler works but it consumes a large amount of memory in time and after several hours, I have a "OutOfMemoryError : java heap space" in my program.

I used Java VisualVM to monitor my program and I found that the netty thread named "nioEventLoopGroup-2-1" consumes lots of memory. If I comment hexadecimal dump and code for aggregation, memory consumption decreases substantially.

[Netty thread memory consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr3o5.jpg)

[Java heap space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoI1P.jpg)

I think my code is causing the problem but I can't find the solution.

Can you help me understand what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I think is better do the 1 and 2 point in the `ServerHandler` class, inside the method `channelRead`